# Experiences with UI Automation and WPF

Tags: wpf, ui-automation

We are developing a rather large WPF based application and would like to include some automated UI testing in our test suite (which already contains a number of unit tests).

The [UI Automation Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) from Microsoft partly sounds like a perfect fit for programatically launching  and interacting with the application in a test setup. However, I've struggled to find solid references for samples and experiences with the technology, the articles and small samples available on MSDN is not enough to convince me that it is a solid choice.

So, does anybody have real world experiences using the UI Automation Framework in their test suite? What are the caveats and the gotchas? Any best practices when written tests scripts, can you "record and replay" to a scriptable format, how much should you facilitate the testing from the application, how did you incorporate it in the automatic build? Should we be looking in another direction than the UI Automation Framework?

Feel free to post you experiences here or link to some good references I might have missed

Comment: This question should not be closed because the answers provide information based on real experience with the technologies. With test automation being rather hot topic right now I bet this information is valuable to many people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where i work we have just started to evaluate some test tools for our system. We came across a tool called [white](http://www.codeplex.com/white), which uses the UI Automation Framework. Note that white does also have a record function although i think it has looks of issues and is still being developed.

What we tried doing was set them up to look like unit tests i.e. `[TestFixture] [Test]` etc.
then we were able to run them through nunit at the same time as the unit tests.

We have found that it can be difficult to access some of the components within your window, but haven't had much of a chance to investigate why.

If you don't mind paying for the software then I would recommend [TestComplete](http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing-tools).

Comment: TestComplete is a click&play tool  while TestStack.White is a C# framework. These are completely different solutions with the former being targeted on testers and the latter on programmers.

Answer (score 6):

I'm in the middle of doing the UI Automation of a WPF app at work. I'm using White and IronRuby and it works great. I've written up how I've done it here: http://www.natontesting.com/2010/02/17/how-to-test-a-wpf-app-using-ironruby-and-white/

Comment: Really nice writeup, Nat. Thumbs up from me

Comment: Wrestling with White became too much of a pain so I wrote bewildr (https://github.com/natritmeyer/bewildr). It's in use at the BBC and working great!

Answer (score 2):

We initially went with white, and then moved away from it. It tries to be generic and abstract over the Win32 API, Winforms, Java apps, and the MS UI automation API. The MS UI automation API is also trying to be generic and abstract over the win32 api and winforms and WPF, so you end up in a "lowest-common-denominator-of-lowest-common-denominator" scenario.

The result of this was that the White element searching API simply wasn't flexible enough to find various UI elements that we needed to find, and it didn't expose enough of the underlying UI automation framework elements for us to do anything useful with it.

We ended up going with a homegrown sort-of-framework; We use the MS UIAutomation framework directly, but have extension methods and helper classes to deal with the scenarios it doesn't address. (Keyboard and Mouse input, primarily).

Note: our test scripts and homegrown framework are all using IronRuby. Ruby's ability to add methods to existing classes and it's flexible syntax (combined with method_missing) are awesome for this kind of thing.

Comment: Edwards, why didn't you tried the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting API (one that is used in Coded UI Test behind the scene)? I'm asking because i just switched to this one from UIA.

Comment: @Nero: Three reasons. Firstly, it didn't exist until the release of visual studio 2010. Secondly, you need to purchase the Premium version of VS instead of the Standard one, which is a HUGE jump in price, particularly here in new zealand. Thirdly, I had a look at the visual studio coded UI test stuff, and didn't like it at all. It was overly complex, not easy to use, and hard to debug. The underlying API code itself may be nicer than the stuff visual studio generates, but I didn't look at that at the time as I didn't realise you could use it independantly