# In Python, how do I automate the control of a UI in a program that uses WPF?

Tags: python, wpf, windows, ironpython, ui-automation

I've been working on this Python program to try to do some automated testing. The problem is that up until recently, I've been able to use pywinauto just fine. Now, I have to control some programs that have their UI made with Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF). So far, I have been using the standard Python interpreter. However, now that I have to deal with this, it might mean having to port to IronPython.

Can someone tell me how I should go about automating the control of programs using WPF for their UI's when my automation program is written in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to send Window Messages to the controls, or simulate key strokes.

Have a look at this question:

[Experiences with UI Automation and WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644158/experiences-with-ui-automation-and-wpf)

Comment: Thanks, eventually got me to an article featuring IronRuby and something called White.